# keeping incorrect letters visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT

In my drag and drop game there is a grid that is populated with words that are hidden from the user. The aim of the game is to spell these words with the aid of a sound and a picture. The user spells a word by dragging and dropping the relevant letters onto the grid.

If the letter is correct it will glow green with the class "wordglow3". If it is wrong it will glow red with "wordglow". As the game is for children I want them to see the letter they drop stays there until the attempt is complete so they can see the word in full so I have used...

```
$(that).html($(ui.draggable).text().trim());
```

to make it stay there. The problem is that if the user gets the word wrong, on the next attempt of the same word this does not work and I don't know why. If the user gets to the next word, it works again for the first attempt and so on. Can anyone help me to make it consistant?

Here is the code that performs the action...

```
if ($(that).data("letter") == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

            $(that).removeClass("wordglow").addClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'white');
            $(that).html($(ui.draggable).text().trim());

        } else {

            $(that).addClass('wordglow');
            $('.drag').css("color", "white");
            $(that).html($(ui.draggable).text().trim());

        }
```

Is there a way I can reset  after each attempts at the word? I have tried making it a variable then resetting it to zero but it did not work.

A fiddle to help - http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/m8Squ/6/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

```
       if ($(that).data("letter") == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

            $(that).addClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'white');
            $('.drag').css("color", "white");
            $(that).html($(ui.draggable).text().trim());


        } else {

            $(that).addClass('wordglow').css('color', 'white');
            $('.drag').css("color", "white");
            $(that).html($(ui.draggable).text().trim());

        }
```